# Xamarin Parse Component refresh current user

Tags: c#, ios, parse-platform, xamarin

How I can refresh ParseUser.CurrentUser in Xamarin for iOS ?

There is no any method like refresh().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Parse forums](https://www.parse.com/questions/update-stale-parseuser-data-android):

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

currentUser.fetchInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            ParseUser currUser = (ParseUser) object;
            // Do Stuff with currUSer
        } else {
            // Failure!
        }
    }
});
```